# 'Sqlite' Could not be found in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone 8
Thy type or namespace name 'SqLite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My process was

- I cloned git repo into my local.
- I added that c++ project (Sqlite) into my existing project.
- Than i added Sqlite-net ( SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs) into my project.
- Than created USE_WP8_NATIVE_SQLITE compilation symbol successfully.

But than i build my project it shows same error for three lines in "SQLite.cs" which are following.

```
using Sqlite3 = Sqlite.Sqlite3;
using Sqlite3DatabaseHandle = Sqlite.Database;
using Sqlite3Statement = Sqlite.Statement;
```

Please help me to solve this problem, my VS2012 is well configured and fulfilling the requirment for creation Sqlite DB into WP8.

Need Help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully done, i was missing the one step that was adding sqlite existing project as a reference. So after completion all steps me have to add SQLite existing project as reference in my existing project.

it worked fine.
Thank you all.